# Web scraping in excel

Tags: excel, vba, web-scraping

I want to pull data from "https://www.oanda.com/currency/converter/" in excel using vba (Eg. From USD to EUR)
I had tried doing the following code..but its still not working

```
Sub PullData()

    Dim IE As Object
    Dim doc As HTMLDocument

    Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    IE.Visible = True

    IE.Navigate "https://www.oanda.com/currency/converter/"

    Do While IE.Busy Or IE.ReadyState <> 4
        Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 1, Now)
    Loop

    Set doc = IE.Document  

    doc.getElementById("quote_currency_input").Value = "EURO"
    doc.getElementById("base_currency_input").Value = "US Dollar"
           Do While IE.Busy Or IE.ReadyState <> 4
        Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 1, Now)
    Loop

    MsgBox doc.getElementsByClassName("want").Item(0).innerText

    IE.Quit

End Sub
```

Comment: What have you tried so far and where do you get stuck?

Comment: Where do you get an error?

Comment: The msgbox is blank

Comment: If you don't get an error, I think the InnerText of the element is empty. If I look at the site, I also notice that they sell their API, so maybe they protected their site from scraping, because I don't see where the value appears that you want to have.

Comment: I want the value which appears in "Amount" text box.. and the website is not protected because i have the same thing working but the coding part is password protected and the employee has absconded the company.

Comment: Then try innerHTML instead of innerText  to see what comes up. I suspect you then need the Value of the input element within the div you selected now.

Comment: It is showing the HTML code, i want the value after conversion..plz help

Comment: I understand it shows the HTML code, but somewhere in that html code it should also show the value that you want. If not, then you are looking at the wrong element.

Answer (score 0):

You can get from outerHTML or from the value attribute of the hidden element

```
Option Explicit
'VBE > Tools > References:
' Microsoft Internet Controls
Public Sub GetData()
    Dim ie As New InternetExplorer
    With ie
        .Visible = True
        .Navigate2 "https://www.oanda.com/currency/converter/"

        While .Busy Or .readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend

       .document.getElementById("quote_currency_input").Value = "EURO"
       .document.getElementById("base_currency_input").Value = "US Dollar"
        Debug.Print .document.querySelector("#form_base_amount_input_hidden").Value
        Debug.Print Split(Split(.document.getElementById("form_base_amount_input_hidden").outerHTML, "value=" & Chr$(34))(1), Chr$(34))(0)
        .Quit
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Can't you get the Value attribute from the element right away instead of taking the outerHTML, since it's an input element.

Comment: Yes you can. Well spotted.

Comment: @Pratham Did you try this before disappearing?